# Prove that $\overline{A \cap B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $\overline{A \cap B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$

How should I begin?

Your comments leads me to this:

If $\overline{A \cap B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$ is true, then

$$\forall x \left(x \in \overline{A \cap B} \rightarrow x \in \overline{A} \cup \overline{B} \right)$$

Suppose we have  $x \in \overline{A \cap B}$ and by the definition of complement

$$x \not \in A \cap B$$

In this case $A \cap B = \left\{x \mid x \in A \ \wedge x \in B \right\}$ is not true. By De Morgan's law from logic we see that $x \not \in A \vee x \not \in B$ but $$x \in \overline{A} \vee x \in \overline{B}$$

by the definition of complement.

Then $A \cup B = \left\{x \mid x \in A \ \vee x \in B \right\}$ is true. This show that
$$\overline{A \cap B} \subseteq \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$$

You can similarly show that $\overline{A} \cup \overline{B} \subseteq \overline{A \cap B}$  and therefore $\overline{A \cap B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$ is proved.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that this is [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Set_theory_and_Boolean_algebra)

Comment: The standard way to show that given two sets $C$ and $D$ that $C=D$, show that $C\subset D$ and $D\subset C$.

Comment: That's right but I have to prove it.

Comment: $A \cap B = \left\{x \mid x \in A \ \wedge x \in B \right\}$ is a definition and therefore automatically true.  You seem to think not only that it is false in this case, but that you can establish that it's false *without any special knowledge about $A$ or $B$*, in which case it would be false for *any* choices of $A$ and $B$.  It shouldn't be hard for you to find a counterexample to that claim.

Answer (score 4):

Prove both inclusions, i.e., $\overline{A\cap B}\subset \overline{A}\cup \overline{B}$ and $\overline{A}\cup \overline{B} \subset \overline{A\cap B}$.

To prove the first, you pick $x\in \overline{A\cap B}$. Then, $x\notin A\cap B$, so either $x\notin A$ or $x\notin B$. You keep on with the reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

1. Whenever you have to prove that two sets are equal, say $X=Y$, you start by writing:

> First, we show that $X\subset Y$. …  Next, we show that $Y\subset X$. … Therefore, $X=Y$.

2. Whenever you have to prove that one set is a subset of another, you start by writing:

> Suppose $x\in X$.  … This shows that $x\in Y$ also.  Therefore, $X\subset Y$.

The “…” parts are the parts you must fill in.  They will be different depending on how $X$ and $Y$ are defined.

---

Here is a tiny example.  Let us show that $A\cap B \subset A$.

> Suppose $x\in A\cap B$.  By the definition of the intersection, we know that $x\in A$ and $x\in B$.  Thus $x\in A$. This shows that any $x$ in $ A\cap B$ is also in $A$. Therefore $A\cap B\subset A$.

Comment: I edited my question see above.

Comment: The half of the proof that you showed in your question looks correct.  If you add a similarly correct proof of $\bar A\cup\bar B\subset \overline{A\cap B}$, you will have the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First draw the Venn diagram. You will visualize that if an element belongs to (A\cap B)^c, then it has to belong to A^c \cup B^c and viceversa. Then intrepret it algebraically. It is easy. Try !

Comment: Yes I edited my question see above.

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, you have to show that $\overline{A \cap B}\subset \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$:
$x\in\overline{A \cap B} \Rightarrow x\not\in A\cap B \Rightarrow x\not\in A \mbox{ or } x\not\in B \Rightarrow x\in \overline{A} \mbox{ or } x\in \overline{B} \Rightarrow x\in \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$

On the other hand, you have to show that $\overline{A \cap B}\subset \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$:
$x\in \overline{A} \cup \overline{B} \Rightarrow x\in \overline{A} \mbox{ or } x\in \overline{B} \Rightarrow x\not\in A \mbox{ or } x\not\in B \Rightarrow x\not\in A\cap B \Rightarrow x\in\overline{A \cap B} $